# Would been vs would have been

Tags: past-tense, conditional-constructions

Having a hard time telling the difference between these, and which ones are wrong.

1) 0.5 seconds later and he **would been** dead.

2) 0.5 seconds later and he **would have been** dead.

3) 0.5 seconds later and he **would be** dead.

Anyone kind enough to explain how to use these 3 forms?
Thanks!

Comment: #1 is ungrammatical: modals like *would* must always be followed by a verb in infinitive form (*would **be*** or *would **have** been*).

Comment: That's what I thought as well, until I saw many examples with "he would been" in here https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/he-d and now I doubt about everything I know.

Comment: Ah! Your mistake is understanding *he'd* as *he **would*** -- in the instances with a past participle it represents *he **had***.

Comment: I see, that explains it haha, my bad then!

Comment: Why don't you delete this question then, since it's likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: @StoneyB I would like to *discourage* deletion, and instead to encourage one of the two of you to post the explanation about "he'd" as an answer, in case someone makes the same mistake in future.  Questions based on misunderstandings can still be useful!

Comment: Until the OP acknowledged @StoneyB’s suggestion, I was going to provide another answer. Here’s the gist, in case it’s worth including in the explanation Darrel suggests. The first of the three may well be heard in spoken English, or rather misheard. It is common for a fluent/native speaker to say “would have” as “would’ve” or even “woulda”. The latter could easily be heard simply as “would” making it sound like the speaker was saying the first form, but was really saying the second.

Comment: @tkp you are also right with this. When a native speaks it might sound as #1 but as said by StoneyB #1 is wrong and my confusion started with the "he'd" contraction.

Answer (score 2):

1) **Wrong**. One way to explain this is 'been' is the past participle of be and should be followed by modal auxiliaries. Other is after would, a basic form of a verb/ infinitive form should be stated.

2)Correct

3)Correct

Editing to describe the 2nd and 3rd.

2) This outputs an imagination/ assumption about a past incident; *0.5 seconds later, if not for something, he would have been dead*. Fortunately, he is not.

3) This is more like an assumption about a present incident. Here, there's a possibility that he is dead after 0.5s.

Comment: Would you please add examples to further explain #2 and #3?

Comment: Please tell me "would have been " what tense is this ??

Comment: "would have been " is perfect continuous conditional tense

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how late I am, but I want to reply this:

> One way to explain this is 'been' is the past participle of be and should be followed by modal auxiliaries.

I think it is easier to explain this by using rule says that 'been' can only be used after 'have' in any form of this verb. That means first sentence is truly wrong.